# Prevent altering the array while it's already being altered asynchronously from somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

In my multiuser live nods.js app, I have a function that [removes a specific element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array). It's an asyn function and can potentially be called by two different users independently and probably at the same time (client-site socket trigger) to perform the operation on the same array.

```
myUsers= [];
myUsers.push('user1');
myUsers.push('user2');
myUsers.push('user3');
```

```
function removeUser(user){
    for(var i=0; i<=myUsers.length; i++){
        if(user===myUsers[i]){
            myUsers.splice(i,1);
            break;
}   }   }
```

Should I be worried that it might lead to removing the wrong/unintended element as a result of both operations happening simultaneously? Like, when `removeUser('user1')` and `removeUser('user3')` are both called at the same time (client-site socket trigger), and while `user1` is being spliced, and `user3` has reached at `i=2` it might remove `user2` instead of `user3`? And `i` might even now go over the loop's original limit (myUsers.length)?

Is my concern valid? If so, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Node.js is single threaded. So, only one function will be executed at a time. The problem you describe is specific to multi-threaded environments only.

For example, though `removeUser('user1')` and `removeUser('user3')` are ready to be executed, they will be pushed in a queue. And the Node.js engine will take the element at the front and executes it and once finishes executing that, picks the next item from the queue. So, `user1` will be removed first and then `user3`.